# IIS7 URL Rewrite with Regex

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a URL rewrite when a user accesses a certain URL of my site:

```
Accessed URL: https://client1.domain.com

Rewritten URL: https://new-client1.otherdomain.com
```

My site has many URLs that point to it, so the simple HTTP redirect module will not be a valid solution for this.  What would the Regex be and what would I want to fill in for each section in a rewrite rule?

Thanks

Comment: I wasn't able to get either of these to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s/client1.domain/new-client1.otherdomain/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern to search for `client1.domain` in order to replace it:

```
(?<=//)([^.]+)\.domain
```

Replace it with a backreference to `client1` and the new domain like so:

```
$1\.otherdomain
```